# Need to debug process as a non admin (VS2010)

Tags: visual-studio

I am running the following
Win7 SP1 Enterprise
VS2010 Pro SP1
Non admin user

I need to attach to the w3wp.exe process
I have assigned myself debug privs via GPO

When attempting to attach to the process I get

Microsoft Visual Studio

Unable to attach to the process. Visual Studio has insufficient privileges to debug this process. To debug this process, Visual Studio must be run as an administrator.

**The main issue is I need to debug a site that handles multiple hostheaders (sitecore)**

Cassini has no concept of hostheaders

IISExpress does not handle hostheaders - cannot launch site with different hostheaders*

Is there an alternative around this ?

Side note
I have tried to give myself admin token with the following as a test as well
http://www.scriptlogic.com/products/privilegeauthority/

VS launches as an 'admin' but gives me the whole Unable to attach to the process. Visual Studio has insufficient privileges to debug this process.

Side note 2
Using process explorer on devenv.exe doesn't show the SeDebugPrivilege enabled
I have tried using ntrights.exe to grant the rights - rebooted and still not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using http://www.scriptlogic.com/products/privilegeauthority/ granting the SeDebug Token as well.

This worked out well as we could also apply this to other products like ants profiler which needed admin rights to run (wasn't required for XP)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an admin password you can (when you open VS) right click, and then say 'run as administrator', otherwise you just may be out of luck as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

This link here: [Working with Web Projects in Visual Studio as a Non-Administrative User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178112.aspx) says it clearly:

> You cannot attach to a process that is running under the IIS worker
>   process because it requires administrative privileges.

Comment: So you can't even grant tthe SeDebug Token, it must be a member of the group ?